# R `update()` formula not working as expected

Tags: r, formula

I am trying to update a model formula produced by `measEq.syntax` function from `semTools`. I provide a base model that is worked by `measEq.syntax`. Sometimes I want to change some stuff in the resulting model syntax, for that propose I used the `update` function, but it is not working as previously:

```r
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9
              general =~ visual + textual + speed'

library(semTools)
#> Loading required package: lavaan
#> This is lavaan 0.6-15
#> lavaan is FREE software! Please report any bugs.
#> 
#> ###############################################################################
#> This is semTools 0.5-6
#> All users of R (or SEM) are invited to submit functions or ideas for functions.
#> ###############################################################################
syntax.config <- measEq.syntax(configural.model = HS.model,
                               data = HolzingerSwineford1939,
                               ID.fac = "ul",
                               group = "school")
fixMeans.c <- '
textual ~ c(0, 0)*1
speed ~ c(0, 0)*1
general ~ c(0, 0)*1
'
syntax.config <- update(syntax.config, change.syntax = fixMeans.c)
#> Error in nValues > 1L && nValues != nBlocks: 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the problem to one of `semTools` package developers, which corrected the package error. Then I just installed the latest GitHub version (i.e., version 0.5-6.922) and the problem is solved.

```r
remotes::install_github("simsem/semTools/semTools") #version 0.5-6.922
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9
              general =~ visual + textual + speed'

library(semTools)
syntax.config <- measEq.syntax(configural.model = HS.model,
                               data = HolzingerSwineford1939,
                               ID.fac = "ul",
                               group = "school")
fixMeans.c <- '
textual ~ c(0, 0)*1
speed ~ c(0, 0)*1
general ~ c(0, 0)*1
'
syntax.config <- update(syntax.config, change.syntax = fixMeans.c)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-15 with [reprex v2.0.2.9000](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>